# How to get x,y from d3.geo.mercator()?

Tags: d3.js

Assuming I have a projection:

```
var xy = d3.geo.mercator(),
path = d3.geo.path().projection(xy);
```

Assuming I have a point at latitude longitude: [51.443737, -0.227966]

How can I use `d3.geo.mercator` and its projection to get the X,Y value?

Comment: Pass the point to the projection?

Comment: How to pass the point to the projection?

Comment: `path` in your code is a function that will take a GeoJSON object and return its projected coordinates. So all you need to do is wrap the coordinates in a Point feature and call the function with it, e.g. something like `{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [51.443737, -0.227966]}`.

Comment: You should actually be able to just invoke `xy` directly -- `xy([51.4, -0.22])`

Comment: Good catch. I was making it more complicated than it should be :) Note that the function takes the coordinate pair in the opposite order though, i.e. [lon, lat].